# How apply if condition if value of x=john or bond

Tags: php

How can display if   if x=john or bond  results you name is john or bond

```
 <?php 
         if ($x == "john")
         { 
      ?> 
you name is john or bond 
             <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($x == "john" || $x == "bond")
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Or if you have many names you can use other structures like `switch()`:

```
switch ($x)
{
    case "john":
    case "bond":
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // or else do this
}
```

You can also use `in_array()` if you have a dynamic list of names or if you just feel like its more readable:

```
if (in_array($x, ["john", "bond"]))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $x="bond";
  //$x="john";
  if ($x == "john" or $x == "bond") {
      echo "Your name is ".$x;
  } 
?>
```